# Appium WinAppDriver C# Calculator example Error

Tags: visual-studio, testing, appium, winappdriver

I'm trying to just run the calculator test C# example (https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/C%23/CalculatorTest) inside visual studio 2017. When I download and build the example, it shows several lines as deprecated;

```
            DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", CalculatorAppId);
            appCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
```

and one as an error that needs to be changed;

```
CalculatorSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

to

```
session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
```

.
I get errors such as this for each test (Addition, division, Multipluication, Substraction, Templatized) when I try and run them:

> Test Name:    Addition Test
>   FullName: CalculatorTest.ScenarioStandard.Addition Test
>   Source:   C:\Users[user]\Downloads\WinAppDriver-master\Samples\C#\CalculatorTest\ScenarioStandard.cs
>   : line 32 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00
>
> Result StackTrace: at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver1..ctor(Uri
>   remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan
>   commandTimeout) at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver1..ctor(Uri
>   remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows.WindowsDriver`1..ctor(Uri
>   remoteAddress, DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities) at
>   CalculatorTest.CalculatorSession.Setup(TestContext context) in
>   C:\Users[user]\Downloads\WinAppDriver-master\Samples\C#\CalculatorTest\CalculatorSession.cs:line
>   42 at CalculatorTest.ScenarioStandard.ClassInitialize(TestContext
>   context) in
>   C:\Users[user]\Downloads\WinAppDriver-master\Samples\C#\CalculatorTest\ScenarioStandard.cs:line
>   101 Result Message:   Class Initialization method
>   CalculatorTest.ScenarioStandard.ClassInitialize threw exception.
>   System.TypeLoadException: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Dispose'
>   in type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumCommandExecutor' from
>   assembly 'appium-dotnet-driver, Version=3.0.0.2, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation..

I have Appium downloaded and running in the background when I do this, but it appears to sit brick like.

I'm a c# app developer, and really don't have a clue what I'm doing with Appium/WinAppDriver (I've just been told to figure it out), and after looking at this for a bit am at a loss as how to troubleshoot whats going on here. I don't know if this is an Appium issue, a WinAppDriver issue, or something else, and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by updating (inside Visual Studio) to the latest beta drivers (4.0.0.4-beta) and then converting code to use the new format.

Use:

```
AppiumOptions options = new AppiumOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Windows");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", NotepadAppId);
            
session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), options);
```

Rather than the shown

```
  DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I didn't have any luck at all with those examples but what I have managed to do is launch an application from it's filepath and test that. I also had to figure out that you must set "Developer Mode" to On (nobody tells you that!) and a few other things. Here are my notes that I made for myself and other developers...

Installing and Running Windows Application Driver

1.Download Windows Application Driver installer from https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases

2.Run the installer on a Windows 10 machine where your application under test is installed and will be tested

3.Set Developer Mode to On (Start -> type "Use Developer Features"), open that and set Developer Mode On...

4.Run WinAppDriver.exe from the installation directory (E.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver)

Install Win App Driver Recorder, then launch it. Click the little yellow rectangle icon at the top of it.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases

Using the above, the examples begin to make more sense but as I said, I have only tested apps where I can launch the executable from it's filepath...